# Construct image from Fabric.js JSON on python server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, canvas, fabricjs

Using python, is it possible to reconstruct an image from the json representation of a fabric.js canvas?

It's easy to do with [Node.js](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4/#node) but I am using django so I prefer not having to run a separate node.js server just to create these images to send them to my django server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to run a separate node server. But you do need a node runtime with the modules - 'canvas' and 'fabric' installed. With that done, you can trivially call the nodejs script from your python code

Here is a sample js script which will read the JSON input and generate a PNG output file

```
var fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    fs = require('fs'),
    out = fs.createWriteStream(process.argv[3]);

var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(530, 630);


canvas.loadFromJSON(process.argv[2], function() {
    canvas.renderAll();

    var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        out.write(chunk);
    });
});
```

And here is how you can call it in your python code

```
import subprocess
fabric_json = u'{"objects": [{"opacity": 1, "strokeMiterLimit": 10, "isMulticolor": false, "height": 203, "visible": true, "stroke": null, "filters": [], "hexColors": ["#085a68", "#ca350a", "#d8ec73"], "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)", "angle": 0, "fillRule": "nonzero", "flipX": false, "flipY": false, "top": 205.78, "scaleX": 0.46, "scaleY": 0.46, "strokeLineJoin": "miter", "width": 200, "backgroundColor": "", "clipTo": null, "type": "image", "strokeLineCap": "butt", "strokeDashArray": null, "strokeWidth": 1, "originY": "top", "originX": "left", "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over", "designId": 2825, "alignY": "none", "alignX": "none", "shadow": null, "crossOrigin": "", "src": "http://localhost.com/designs/sampleimage.png", "meetOrSlice": "meet", "designFileName": "sampleimage.png", "left": 208.68}], "backgroundImage": {"opacity": 1, "strokeMiterLimit": 10, "height": 630, "visible": true, "stroke": null, "filters": [], "fill": "rgb(0,0,0)", "angle": 0, "fillRule": "nonzero", "flipX": false, "flipY": false, "top": 0, "scaleX": 1, "scaleY": 1, "strokeLineJoin": "miter", "width": 530, "backgroundColor": "", "clipTo": null, "type": "image", "strokeLineCap": "butt", "strokeDashArray": null, "strokeWidth": 1, "originY": "top", "originX": "left", "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over", "alignY": "none", "alignX": "none", "shadow": null, "crossOrigin": "", "src": "http://localhost.com:5000/static/images/fabric/ts_rne_front.png", "meetOrSlice": "meet", "left": 0}, "background": "#bf1515"}'
subprocess.call(["node", "fabricImageGenerator.js", fabric_json, "outputImage.png"])
```

Answer (score 2):

**No**.

I don't see how it's possible without writing Python port of Fabric (or a custom parser+renderer).

**Here's why**:

JSON data string contains custom representation of various Fabric shapes, which — during parsing and interpretation by Fabric's `loadFromJSON` — are all loaded and rendered onto canvas. The canvas could then be used to generate an image.

You can parse data in python, since it's just JSON. You can walk over it and analyze it. You'll even be able to "see" the kinds of shapes that need to be loaded onto canvas. But you'll still need the main thing — creating visual representation of each of those shapes.

Unless you do that manually (using some kind of graphics methods in Python; which sounds like a whole lot of work), I don't think there's much else that can be done.